# Call jquery masonry using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-masonry, masonry

i'm trying to get angularjs to work with jquery masonry. Without angular i have managed to get masonry to work fine including css. However, i have used angular to script the whole web app and i now load items dynamically via angular. Since masonry needs to be reloaded after dynamically adding data, i have written a directive to listen to last element of the items in angular repeat so that i can call the jquery masonry. When i call masonry, for some reason the items gets all weird up and does not load when it loaded initially without ng-repeat. Please check the code given below and tell me what im doing wrong here. I wish i had plunkr/js fiddler but since i pull data from a backend i cannot replicate the same.

The library i use is called "**masonry.pkgd.js**"

```
<div id="container" class="masonry js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer", "itemSelector": ".item", "isFitWidth": true }'>
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>-
         <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="{{item.class}}" newsitemupdated>       
             <?php $this->load->view('item') ?>
         </div>                 
 </div>

app.directive('newsitemupdated', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                     masonryUpdate();
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

var masonryUpdate = function() {

            var $container = $('#container').masonry({
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                itemSelector: '.item',
                isFitWidth: true
            });

                setTimeout(function() {

//                    $('#container').masonry();                    
                    $container.masonry('reloadItems');
                    console.log('called');

                }, 500);

}
```

This is how it looks below i reload items.

[image]

This is how it looks after i reloaditems

[image]

Please tell me what im doing wrong and how i can call reload items after ng-repeat to load jquery masonry how its supposed to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed by doing the following

First i write a function to initialize my masonry with options

```
function BuildMasonry() {

    var $container = $('#container').masonry();

    $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: true
    });
}
```

Afterwards i will call it when ng-repeat finishes loading.

```
var masonryUpdate = function() {

    $('#container').masonry('reloadItems');
    BuildMasonry();
}
```

Hope this helps to someone out there :)

Comment: how do you detect when ng-repeat finishes loading?

Comment: You can use a directive and on the scope.$last, update masonry.

Comment: Hi, do you declare these functions inside angularjs module with directive, or where? What does 'reloadItems' refer to here?? Thank you so much.

Comment: That's correct. create a directive using the angular controller you have defined. 

reload items calls to update masonry once all are loaded. Thats it!